# I need an SQL Query to compare Table1.field1 with Table2.field4, cut paste Table2.FoundRow results to Table3

Tags: c#, t-sql

Working on a project using sqlServer 2008.

**EDIT** for clarification : table 1 contains 1 field that has to be matched to Table2.field6 , if theres a match that row needs to be updated with DateTime.Month

`string compareVals = "SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field4 and change table2.field6 to"+ DateTime.Month.ToString();`

Comment: could you explain what datetime.month is ? Is the the month of the current year. If so, it will be better to handle that with sql

Comment: yup, the month of the current year

Comment: then i made it a bit easier for you, check my sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string CompareVals =  
"UPDATE t2
SET field6 = month(getdate())
FROM Table2 t2 
JOIN Table1 t1
ON t1.Field1 = t2.Field4"
```

Comment: thanks alot for the quick reply, please see my edit, I realize I wasn't entirely clear

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to update `Table2.Field6`; so your query will look like this.

```
string CompareVals =
    @"update Table2
        set Table2.field6 = '" + DateTime.Month.ToString() + '" +
    @"    from Table1.field1
        where Table2.Field4 = Table1.Field1";
```

Comment: thanks alot for the quick reply, please see my edit, I realize I wasn't entirely clear

Comment: @Dani, my answer is still applicable to your edit, just have a try and note the where condition, `where Table2.Field4 = Table1.Field1` is matching which you are required for